# Пространства имен

Tags: xml, xaml, soap

Вопрос носит теоретический характер.

В таких языках разметки как xml, xaml, soap и т.д., существуют пространства имен. Зачем они нужны? Как я понял, из опыта общения с данными языками, пространства можно использовать для валидации по схеме? Чем они еще полезны? Также, как я понял, можно задавать несуществующею схему, т.е.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:GetStockPrice xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
      <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
    </m:GetStockPrice>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

При этом, пространство http://www.example.org/stock не существует. Тогда зачем его задавать?

Если где не прав, поправьте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пространства имён созданы для того, чтобы не было проблем из-за конфликтов имён. 
Наприменр, если вдруг окажется, что существует два разных тэга StockName, то их можно будет отличить благодаря тому, что они в разных пространствах имён.

> > http://www.example.org/stock не существует

Что значит не существует? Его объявили в доркументе. Этого достаточно.

Comment: Получается, пространства имен можно сравнить с аналогом из С++? А для чего их еще используют?

Comment: Да, это и есть пространство имён как в C++ и используется с теми же целями. Просто XML - это не C++ и отсюда своя специфика.